# Adding custom meta boxes to specified custom post type

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, post-meta, metabox

In previous situations I have been able to add a custom meta field to posts, the code was this:

```
function website_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'website-website',
        __('Website', 'website'),
        'website_html',
        'post',
        'normal',
        'default'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'website_add_meta_box');

function website_html($post) {
    wp_nonce_field('_website_nonce', 'website_nonce'); ?>

    <p>Information about users website.</p>

    <p>
        <label for="website_website_url"><?php _e('Website URL', 'website'); ?></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="website_website_url" id="website_website_url" value="<?php echo website_get_meta('website_website_url'); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="website_website_source_code"><?php _e('Website Source Code', 'website'); ?></label><br>
        <textarea name="website_website_source_code" id="website_website_source_code" ><?php echo website_get_meta('website_website_source_code'); ?></textarea>
    </p><?php
}

function website_save($post_id) {
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;
    if (!isset($_POST['website_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['website_nonce'], '_website_nonce' )) return;
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) return;

    if (isset($_POST['website_website_url']))
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'website_website_url', esc_attr($_POST['website_website_url']));
    if (isset($_POST['website_website_source_code']))
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'website_website_source_code', esc_attr($_POST['website_website_source_code']));
}
add_action('save_post', 'website_save');
```

My question is how can this code be adapted to apply only to the custom post type of 'website'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth parameter is `$screen`, which in your case is set to `post`, so all you have to do is specify the `website` post type instead:

```php
function website_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'website-website',
        __('Website', 'website'),
        'website_html',
        'website',
        'normal',
        'default'
    );
}
```

Documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

As an aside, your `save_post` hook applies to any post or custom post type being saved, but if `website_website_url` and `website_website_source_code` only apply to the `website` post type, you can add an additional check:

```php
function website_save($post_id) {
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;
    if (!isset($_POST['website_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['website_nonce'], '_website_nonce' )) return;
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) return;
    if (get_post_type($post_id) !== 'website') return;

    if (isset($_POST['website_website_url']))
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'website_website_url', esc_attr($_POST['website_website_url']));
    if (isset($_POST['website_website_source_code']))
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'website_website_source_code', esc_attr($_POST['website_website_source_code']));
}
```

Comment: Spot on buddy! Thanks for contributing!